# Values don't change in for loop

Tags: vb.net, list, reference

I have a `List` of structure's in my VB.NET program, and I'm looping over them, and change the values of the objects in the list, as follows

```
Dim retvals As List(Of SomeStruct) = parser.RetrieveData(new_path)

 For i As Integer = 0 To retvals.Count - 1 Step 1
 dim temp as SomeStruct = retvals(i)

  temp.A = GetValueForA()
  temp.B = GetValueForB() 

 Next
```

When I look into my List of structs after this loop, none of the values were overwritten. Why?  I thought that I had references in my list, so if I change reference A to a struct, then reference B to the same struct should see the changes?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what the problem was, the `Structure` in .NET is a *value type*, meaning the contents will get **copied** into the `List`.  So changing the `temp` variable will not change the original in the `List`

I fixed it by using a `class` instead, which is a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are a value type, whereas classes are a reference type. If you were to be using SomeClass instead of SomeStruct this code would work as you expect.

In the scenario of using a Class, retvals would be a list of pointers to class objects. "dim temp as ..." creates a copy of the pointer, and setting temp.A to something changes the object the pointer points to. So when the code is done, the pointer in the retval still points to the same object which has now been changed.
However, when using structs no pointers are stored. retvals is simply a list of the values stored in your structs. The "dim temp as ..." creates a copy of the entire struct. You modify this struct by changing temp.A, but the original struct never changes since you only modified a copy of it.